# Setter in DataTrigger does not seem to trigger

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

We're developing a *Xamarin Forms* (v2.3.0.107) application with *MVVMLight*, primarily implemented in XAML.

For months we've had a `LoginView` in our app that uses `DataTriggers` to display the current step in a login procedure (Environment Selection -> Credentials -> Verification Code). The view has always done it's part thus far, but now it's not even showing any content, **as if the `DataTriggers` are never triggered**.
Nothing has been changed directly on this View and it's ViewModel, and most indirect changes are rather irrelevant to the issue.

**The LoginView**

```
<ContentPage
    x:Class="MyProject.Views.LoginView"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels;assembly=MyProject"
    BindingContext="{Binding [LoginViewModel], Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}">
    <Grid>
        <StackLayout
            IsVisible="False">
            <StackLayout.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger 
                    TargetType="StackLayout" 
                    Binding="{Binding LoginStatus}" 
                    Value="{x:Static viewmodels:LoginStatus.Login}">
                    <Setter 
                        Property="IsVisible" 
                        Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </StackLayout.Triggers>
            ...
        </StackLayout>
        ...
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

**The LoginViewModel**

```
namespace MyProject.ViewModels
{
    public enum LoginStatus
    {
        Login,
        EnvironmentSelection,
        InstanceSelection,
        VerificationCode
    }

    public class LoginViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private LoginStatus _loginStatus;
        public LoginStatus LoginStatus
        {
            get { return _loginStatus; }
            private set { Set(ref _loginStatus, value); }
        }

        public LoginViewModel()
        {
            LoginStatus = LoginStatus.Login;
        }
    }
}
```

**What I've tried thus far**

I use the following `DebugConverter` to debug binding:

```
public class DebugConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        return value;
    }
}
```

I've changed the binding for the StackLayout DataTrigger to:

```
Binding="{Binding LoginStatus, Converter={StaticResource DebugConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static viewmodels:LoginStatus.Login}}"
```

This allows me to verify that whatever I receive from the ViewModel is indeed the Value I provide in the DataTrigger. And indeed, both `value` and `parameter` parameters in the converter are the enum value `MyProject.ViewModels.LoginStatus.Login`. Even when I do a quick watch on `value == parameter` I get true as result.

Also, when I set the `StackLayout`'s `IsVisible` to True, it **DOES** show me the content.

**What does this tell me?**

- My `LoginView`'s BindingContext bound to the `LoginViewModel`.
- The Binding of my DataTrigger is indeed bound to `LoginStatus` and has the correct value (this shouldn't even change initially anyway).
- The Value in my DataTrigger also returns the correct value.
- The condition for DataTrigger is valid, so the Setter should trigger.

I've implemented such basic triggers a lot in WPF and it has ever since worked in Xamarin. How come this implementation suddenly decides fail? I must've checked the Setter implementation about 10 times, but I just cannot see any errors in the syntax.

Am I missing anything? According to search results this is not a common issue...

Comment: Are there any errors in the output window for the `Binding`? Have you tried changing the `TraceLevel` to try and get more useful information out? [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.presentationtracesources.tracelevel(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That doesn't seem to be supported in PCL, I guess it's for WPF applications? I've read that Binding tracing does not work when debugging in iOS, which I use to debug. Unfortunately I currently cannot run in android either due to some incompatibility error.

Comment: Oh that is a pain. If the converter is working and the value parameter is coming through with the expected `LoginStatus` could you not modify the converter to return a `bool` to drive the `IsVisible` property?

Comment: Sounds like a valuable solution, but unfortunately the results quite the opposite now. Using such converter to verify equality displays all separate contents at the same time, while the converter only returns true once and false for all other content views. I just noticed commands do not work either, so something is structurally wrong. It seems like the View does not react to any change since `InitializeComponent()`.

Comment: I found the source of the issue, my own dumb mistake... I'll post the answer in a few minutes for the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the issue was my own stupid mistake...

I extended the our `NavigationService` to allow for an optional ViewModel to be defined, but I forgot to verify whether the handed ViewModel is not null. So after the `ViewModelLocator` initialized `BindingContext`, the `NavigationService` would override `BindingContext` with `null`.

I did not notice this behavior because the `DebugConverter` is not called when `BindingContext` is set to `null`. Instead it will invalidate any Triggers that utilize the `BindingContext` and revert any Setters that were called.